# List all files changed by a specific user in a Git repository

Tags: git

How do I get a list of all files changed by a specific user in a Git repository?

Using `$ git blame` will tell you who has changed each line of a file, but that's only limited to one file, includes the whole line by default, and doesn't include historic changes that might have been overwritten.

I  would like some command (or short script) that will produce a list of all files changed by a specific user.

```
code/modules/abacus.dm
code/game/world.dm
interface/stylesheet.css
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git log --pretty= --committer=<username> --name-only | sort -u
```

`--pretty=` suppresses the contents of commit logs as you don't need them here. `--committer=<username>` limits the output to commits whose committer is `username`. If you want author name, use `--author=<username>` instead. `--name-only` prints the changed files of these commits. `sort -u` sorts the list and removes redundant files.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the list of all the files changed by the author:

> git whatchanged --author="author name" --no-commit-id --name-only